# Asterisk DTMF sometimes gets ignored (but only for some people)

Tags: java, asterisk, dtmf, agi

I have a very strange problem and don't even know where to begin to look.

We're using AGI and the Java libraries to present an IVR but have gotten complaints from the users that their keypresses are being ignored.

In my **sip.conf**, under the **general** section, I have DTMF defined like this (the "relax" line being commented out):

```
dtmfmode = rfc2833
;relaxdtmf=yes
```

I've confirmed with the provider that it should be **rfc2833** as that is what they specifically configured for us.

I turned on **dtmf** debug level in my **logger.conf** to my **messages** file:

```
messages => notice,warning,error,dtmf
```

I now see lines like these:

```
DTMF[8744] channel.c: DTMF begin '1' received on SIP/veracity-00005052
DTMF[8744] channel.c: DTMF begin ignored '1' on SIP/veracity-00005052
DTMF[8744] channel.c: DTMF end '1' received on SIP/veracity-00005052, duration 270 ms
DTMF[8744] channel.c: DTMF end passthrough '1' on SIP/veracity-00005052
DTMF[8741] channel.c: DTMF begin '1' received on SIP/veracity-00005056
DTMF[8741] channel.c: DTMF begin ignored '1' on SIP/veracity-00005056
DTMF[8741] channel.c: DTMF end '1' received on SIP/veracity-00005056, duration 415 ms
DTMF[8741] channel.c: DTMF end passthrough '1' on SIP/veracity-00005056
```

The fact that it says, "ignored" concerns me but I haven't read any info or forum posts that would indicate this is unwanted behavior.

The Java code that receives the input looks like this.  Basically it acts whatever digit gets returned by **key** or-- if it's zero-- replays the menu.

```
char key = 0;

if ( validOptions.contains( "1" ) )
    key = agiChan.streamFile( menu( "menu1" ), validOptions );

if ( validOptions.contains( "2" ) && key == 0 )
    key = agiChan.streamFile( menu( "menu2" ), validOptions );

if ( validOptions.contains( "3" ) && key == 0 )
    key = agiChan.streamFile( menu( "menu3" ), validOptions );

if ( !validOptions.contains( "1" ) && !validOptions.contains( "2" ) && key == 0 )
    key = agiChan.streamFile( menu( "menu4" ), validOptions );

if ( key == 0 )
    key = agiChan.waitForDigit( 5000 );

return key;
```

I'm at a loss on this one, especially since it doesn't happen for everyone.  Where would I even start looking/debugging something like this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Quick update:  I uncommented the line that has "relaxdtmf" and set it to yes.  I'll watch the log file to see if I'm still getting input ignored.

Comment: Our provider made a change on their end and the problem seems to have gone away.  I still don't know the cause (or even the solution).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's generally from the providers end because the signal is sent/received from the providers, always try using different dtmf modes.